# How to find the table name which have some particular column in PostgreSQL using pgadmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am using PGAdmin for executing a query , If there is 30 tables in database and one column XYZ is used in min 10 to 15 table So, how can i get the tables in which that particular column is used.

Kindly help me out

Answer (score 2):

You can use the information_schema views:

```
select table_schema, 
       table_name
from information_schema.columns
where column_name = 'xyz';
```

Comment: It gives output but no data

Comment: What do you mean with "no data". If the statement returns something then obviously it returns data. The statement _will_ show the tables with those column names.

Comment: its not showing any table name or column name, return blank

Comment: Then you do not have a table with a column named `xyz`

Comment: I have a table which having column name XYZ

Comment: Then update the above answer as where column_name = 'XYZ'; and try.

Comment: If there is no result, it means you don't have any table or have a typo on column_name you typed. Remember that it's case sensitive.

Comment: You do not have a column name XYZ, you may have a column name "XYZ". Postgres lower cases all object names, which includes column names, unless they are double quoted when created. If double quoted when created then they must **always be double quoted**.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on your schema then you will find a option search objects.
Click on the option and select the option you want to search from the new opened window.
Now fill the pattern as name or as per the option you have selected with prefix and suffix as "%".

Answer (score 0):

just do the right-click on the databases list, refresh, schemas, public, tables
When I was learning pgadmin and postgresql, I found this tool helpful, as it allows to play with the ui
http://choose.tools/tool

Answer (score 0):

```
    select t.table_schema,
       t.table_name
from information_schema.tables t
inner join information_schema.columns c on c.table_name = t.table_name 
                                and c.table_schema = t.table_schema
where c.column_name = 'last_name'
      and t.table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
      and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
order by t.table_schema;
```

Replace that 'last_name' with your column XYZ

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just override the "column_x" for your desired column:

```
> select t.table_schema,
>        t.table_name from information_schema.tables t inner join information_schema.columns c on c.table_name = t.table_name 
>                                 and c.table_schema = t.table_schema where c.column_name = 'column_x'
>       and t.table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
>       and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE' order by t.table_schema;
```

Original from *https://dataedo.com/kb/query/postgresql/find-tables-with-specific-column-name*